# Regression/Optimization with two unknown matrices

Tags: optimization, regression, nonlinear-optimization

I the matrices $V$ and $V_L$ and want to find two matrices $M,N$ s.t.
$$||M V N - V_L || \rightarrow min.$$

My first idea was to initialize $M$ and $N$ randomly and then solve the problem as:
$$M_1 = arg min_M ||M V N_0 - V_L ||$$
$$N_1 = arg min_N ||M_1 V N - V_L ||$$
$$ ... $$
and so on.
What do you think or are there any algorithm, which can help me here?
Looked pretty much around, but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: $I$ is perhaps not the best name to choose for a matrix that is not the identity matrix ...

Comment: Sure, thanks. Edited.